# DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE not showing message to user

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlplus, dbms-output

I am trying to create a trigger that would check for a null value in column namesdreservation_status from my table passenger and set it to a default value if it's null and show the user a message of it being set to default.

The trigger is created and works fine for setting the default but no message is shown to the user.

```
create or replace trigger mytrigger
    before insert or update on passenger
    for each row
    when (new.reservation_status IS NULL)
begin
    IF :new.reservation_status IS NULL THEN
        :new.reservation_status := 'not reserved';
        dbms_output.put_line('reservation status invalid, set to default');
    end IF;
end mytrigger
/
```

The value gets changed to 'not reserved' if its null but the message 'reservation status invalid, set to default' isn't displayed. Help.

Comment: are you running from sqlplus?  You need to execute "set serveroutput on"

Comment: yes, i am using sqlplus. I did set serveroutput to on outside the trigger it did not do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trigger's don't do anything until they're actually triggered - in this case, on an INSERT.

```
clear screen
set serveroutput on

drop table passenger;
create table passenger (id integer, reservation_status varchar2(25));

create or replace trigger mytrigger
    before insert or update on passenger
    for each row
    when (new.reservation_status IS NULL)
begin
    IF :new.reservation_status IS NULL THEN
        :new.reservation_status := 'not reserved';
        dbms_output.put_line('reservation status invalid, set to default');
    end IF;
end mytrigger;
/

insert into passenger values (1, null);
commit;
```

If I run this in SQLPlus, SQLcl, or SQL Developer -

[image]

And if we check the table, you can see our trigger, 'worked.'

[image]